# Is dalgona coffee without sugar still "fluffy"?

Tags: instant, flavored-coffee

Would love to make dalgona coffee without sugar - is the granulated sugar necessary to keep the coffee "fluffy"? The recipe calls for two tablespoons of sugar - are there are some sweetener alternatives that will give you the same "fluffy" texture as using granulated sugar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just made one batch with [Xylitol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylitol):

[image]

Other websites also recommend [Erythritol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erythritol) - which isn’t surprising, considering that both are sugar alcohols. (Note that both can have a laxative effect, individual tolerance varies.)

Apparently the (non-)sugar granules aren’t even required, I have seen (albeit not tested myself) recipes that use liquid sweeteners, e.g. [this one with maple syrup](https://cradlekitchen.com/whipped-coffee-recipe-with-maple-syrup/), but I have also read posts that claim that they whip well, but that the stability of the foam is not the best.